# Flask lost client's post response

Tags: python, post, flask, decorator

Suppose there is a view of the function is as follows:

```
@app.route('/cat/'， methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@check_something(check='cat')
def cat():
    print 'cat'
    return 'cat'

@app.route('/dog/'， methods=('GET', 'POST'))
@check_something(check='dog')
def dog():
    print 'dog'
    return 'dog'
```

Here， I used a decorator named check_something(), what i want to do is to check the condition before execute mainfanction. The decorator function code is :

```
def check_something(check=''):
    def decorator(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
            print('check_start')
            if check == 'dog':
                return jsonify( ret='check dog' )
            else:
                ctx = f(*args, **kwargs)
                return jsonify( ret=ctx )
        return decorated_function
    return decoration
```

I test it from android client and web client, below are the test results:

```
Android + GET: route 'cat' is OK, route 'dog' is OK;
Web + GET    : route 'cat' is OK, route 'dog' is OK;
Android +POST: route 'cat' is OK, route 'dog' is Failed, raise SocketTimeoutException;
Web + POST: i didn't test it.
```

**Why? It's so strange!**

Let me talk about some personal speculation.

**1.It is caused by the decorator.***Flask's decorator @app.route() wil record the decorated function. And so I added functools.wraps(f) for keep function's feature. But when program execute check_something(check='dog'), it didn't execute f(*args, **kwargs), so flask lose the decorated function's feature. And so flask lose response. I guess.

**2.But why the GET can execute success?** Maybe there have some problem between Flask and POST. I guess, too.

Can anyone give me some help? Thanks!

Comment: Just tried both GET + POST (web), worked fine. One thing, in the check_something function, the most outer return should be returning `decorator` instead of `decoration`.

Comment: I do not see you checking for the request method. ("methods" only specifies the allowed methods) 
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#http-methods

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in your decorator. f is the function being decorated and if there
is a test f is not being executed. a corrected version:

```
 print('check_start')
 if check == 'dog':
      ctx = f(*args, **kwargs)
      return jsonify( ret='check dog' )
 else:
      ctx = f(*args, **kwargs)
      return jsonify( ret=ctx
```